# Remove title tooltip on hover but not in HTML

Tags: html, css, attributes, attr

On the following site:

[Link to site with issues](http://gregorydanelian.comule.com/ken/)

I have three buttons at the bottom of each thumbnail (hover to see them). The three buttons open up a prettyphoto box that uses the title attribute under the image (hidden as white currently next to the gallery nav buttons).

I need the HMTL title attribute to remain within the HTML. I just do not need the ugly tooltip when you hover over the buttons.

Does anyone know how to remove hover title tooltip on links?

Comment: R U already done with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after a workaround like this:

First put a class `suppress` on every link you want its tool-tip to be removed on hover:

```
<a class="suppress" title="">link text</a>
```

Then you may have this snippet in your code:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].className == 'suppress') {
        links[i]._title = links[i].title;
        links[i].onmouseover = function() { 
            this.title = '';
        }
        links[i].onmouseout = function() { 
            this.title = this._title;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I have added: `<script>
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].className == 'suppress') {
        links[i]._title = links[i].title;
        links[i].onmouseover = function() { 
            this.title = '';
        }
        links[i].onmouseout = function() { 
            this.title = this._title;
        }
    }
}
</script>` within the <head> tags. All it seems to do is affect the font-family of that link button

Comment: It works to remove the hover but it also removes the lightbox link in the caption when the gallery is opened.

Comment: This snippet does not do anything but temporarily replacing the `title` attribute of `a`s which have `suppress` class, so believe that there is no magic behind this. For this question, this is a complete answer. If you are facing further problems in your job, feel free to ask separate questions, as they are really separate.